# Use LEFT JOIN between two table in HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, hibernate3

I have two [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_Java_object) classes. One is EmployeeTO and another one is AddressTO.

EmployeeTO has one variable with name EmployeeId and AddressTO also has one variable with name EmployeeId. I want to apply a left join between EmployeeTO's EmployeeId and AddressTO's EmployeeId using HQL.

I used the following query.

```
from EmployeeTO employeeTO LEFT JOIN AddressTO addressTO ON employeeTO .EmployeeId=addressTO.EmployeeId
```

But it shows an error:

> line 1:139: unexpected token: ON

Comment: are they mapped with ManyToOne etc?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski No But EmployeeTO Table contains all EmployeeID whereas  AddressTO table contains some EmployeeID which also present into the EmployeeTO

Comment: Instead of ON use WITH clause

Answer (score 4):

There is no `ON` clause in an HQL join:

```
from EmployeeTO e
left join e.addressTO
```

This assumes that your `Employee` entity class has an `AddressTO` field called `addressTO`.

Comment: in e.addressTO addressTO's a will be in lower case?

Comment: @VishalMittal All the names should match the underlying entities.